# Считать файл по колонкам и преобразовать str в float

Tags: python

такой вопрос, мне нужно считать данные по столбцам с .lvm файла, при этом нужно преобразовать данные во float. Вот что я пока пробовал:

```
col1 = []
col2 = []
col3 = []
new_list = []
with open (r'C:\\Users\\Пётр\\Documents\\LabVIEW Data\\8APSK\\8APSK_20dB_2.lvm', 'r') as f:

    for line in f:
        first, second, third = line.split()
        col1.append(first)
        col2.append(second)
        col3.append(third)
    
        new_list = list(map(float, col1))
    
print (new_list)



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-a3b0bf4d1892> in <module>
     11         col3.append(third)
     12 
---> 13         new_list = list(map(float, col1))
     14 
     15 print (new_list)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0,000000'
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно преобразовать данные.
Пример файла https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NJvcaECbI_W5rkBQkmrkn4aSNe650S9q/view?usp=sharing

Comment: поменяйте запятые на точки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`,` надо заменить на `.` и после этого преобразовать в `float`

```
new_list = [float(el.replace(",", ".")) for el in col1]
```

Answer (score 2):

как написал @Danis - можно просто переименовать запятую в точку и дальше уже работать как с обычными строками через `float`

можно также использовать локализации, например:

```
import locale

locale._override_localeconv["decimal_point"] = ","

val = locale.atof("12,13")
print(val)
```

это конечно еще тот микроскоп для такого гвоздя, но как вариант... :)